# IIS Log Query to Match Azure Application Insights

Tags: sql, iis, iis-8

I need to match, as best as possible, the following Azure Application Insights query to a query for a local IIS log file using IIS Log Parser.

Kusto Query for AppInsights:

```
requests
| where timestamp between(todatetime('2019-05-06T15:15:00.000')..todatetime('2019-05-06T15:22:00.000'))
| order by timestamp desc
| summarize count() by url
| order by count_
```

IIS Log Query Code:

```
SELECT cs-uri-stem as Url, 
FROM 'C:\users\xxxx\Documents\u_ex'
WHERE to_time(time)
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP ('15:15:00','hh:mm:ss') AND TIMESTAMP('15:22:00','hh:mm:ss')
AND DATE = '2019-05-06'
COUNT(*) As Hits
GROUP BY cs-uri-stem  
ORDER By Hits DESC
```

Error I get in IIS query:

> Error parsing query: Syntax Error: : expecting FROM
>   keyword instead of token C:\users\xxxx\Docments\u+ex190506.log" [SQL
>   query syntax invalid or unsupported.]

Comment: Move COUNT(*) As Hits to the end of the first row.

Comment: I still get the same error after making this change.

Comment: Two fixes to get this working. 1) Moved the log file to C:\temp AND 2) select cs-uri-stem as Url, count(*) As Hits FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' where date='2019-05-06' and time >= '15:15:00' and time <= '15:22:00'
GROUP BY cs-uri-stem  
ORDER By Hits DESC